# Looping Through Dictionary Values in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have a script that calculates the average of all quiz, homework, and exam scores of all students in a course. Then, I want it to compare how each student did on each item compared to the average for the item using dictionaries. How could I go about this?

```
from __future__ import division

def main():
    quiz_averages = quiz_average(remove_zeros([57,0,36,29,38,31,33,0,42,0,52,28,0,50,26,97,80,63,8,36,33,39,12,36,12,59,75,61,57,39,18,9,19,35,75,5,18,0,56,0,24,0,9],
                                              [83,0,64,45,66,82,52,0,43,0,53,49,43,82,44,74,74,58,52,52,60,18,24,34,19,42,72,65,79,99,75,24,35,70,74,43,55,0,82,0,34,0,22],
                                              [69,0,38,16,16,16,55,0,28,0,44.5,31,0,33,52,75,46,33,36,0,49,34.5,35,79.5,13,27,31,52,40.5,64.5,15,0,31,47,26,0,36,0,68,0,64.5,0,20],
                                              [86,0,95,74,90,53,32,0,79,0,38,63,0,42,61,0,0,70,62,78,0,60,47,89,75,62,84,62,71,80,73,0,31,25,74,0,77,0,90,0,78,0,25]))
    student_quiz_scores = {'John':[61,65,52,62],'Kate':[87,56,73,24],'Mike':[97,54,84,42],'Danielle':[39,100,35,75],'Roger':[78,65,37,42]}
    print_quiz_averages(student_quiz_scores,quiz_averages)

    homework_averages = homework_average(remove_zeros([74,70,62,98,70,83,24,70,87,14,67,80,93,72,65,90,23,43,95,53,66,98,100,95,82,88,91,90,55,64,71,86,66,89,38,88],
                                                      [80,71,58,68,80,71,3,47,60,65,72,87,36,67,57,61,32,29,37,46,73,72,99,67,77,93,93,40,68,84,53,74,84,52],
                                                      [44,25,62,85,77,80,45,80,70,25,80,73,53,56,82,70,67,36,46,82,85,40,85,42,64,84,80,58,63,73,84,89,87,55,82],
                                                      [93,70.5,59,94,97,98.5,70,94,70.5,86,97.5,100,87,77.5,71,79,86,93.5,67,50,94,94,73.5,100,82,81,99.5,77.5,91.5,75.5,94,94,45,91.5],
                                                      [93.5,65,71,96,96,95,78,96,96,76,94,91.5,48,74,96,75,95,49,89,94,95,98,96,62,61,94,68,91,96,80,61,93],
                                                      [79,78,74,97.5,88,99.5,77,96,94,87.5,94,96.5,55,94,55,37,53,76.5,97,97.5,80,97.5,38,78,95.5,72,59,74,97.5,97.5,52,97.5],
                                                      [82,88,43,87,68,100,82,92,81,90,100,100,85.5,94,51,74,54,95,94,89,95,77,59,94.5,72,72,32,94,90,90,97],
                                                      [86.5,94,94,94.5,89,89,78,72,99,100,99.5,72,78,71.5,76,56,81,79,80,85.5,89,73,73.5,100,93,68,88,92,95,100,80.5]))
    student_homework_scores = {'John':[95,99,85,100,96,97.5,95,89],'Kate':[88,97,86,78,41,81,94,96],'Mike':[89,88,81,85,99,57,69,100],'Danielle':[75,87,67,59,94,92,94,95],'Roger':[97,78,87,93,91,90,67,84]}
    print_homework_averages(student_homework_scores,homework_averages)

   exam_averages = exam_average(remove_zeros([85,80,85,77,83,67,55,75,79,76,72,59,89,87,73,85,78,84,69,75,84,52,85,76,84,90,85,84,80,76,86,75,89,71,64],
                                             [85,89,76,76,85,83,82,83,78,60,79,80,91,86,78,75,93,81,53,80,83,79,73,78,83,77,92,91,77,73,86,77,88,48,73]))
student_exam_scores = {'John':[84,83],'Kate':[93,78],'Mike':[85,73],'Danielle':[100,98],'Roger':[66,88]}
print_exam_averages(student_exam_scores,exam_averages)

def remove_zeros(*all_quizzes):
    result = []
    for each_quiz in all_quizzes:
        updated_quiz_list = []
        for number in each_quiz:
            if number != 0:
                updated_quiz_list.append(number)
        result.append(updated_quiz_list)
    return result

def quiz_average(all_quizzes):
    averages = []
    for each_quiz in all_quizzes:
        each_average = find_average(each_quiz)
        averages.append(each_average)
    return averages

def find_average(array):
    for number in array:
        average = sum(array)/len(array)
    return average

def print_quiz_averages(student_quiz_scores,the_averages):
    count = 0
    for i in the_averages:
        print "The average for quiz",count+1,"is:",i
        count+=1
        if student_quiz_scores[count-1]>the_averages[count-1]:
            print "You did", student_quiz_scores[count-1]-the_averages[count-1], "points higher than the average! :)\n"
        else:
            print "You did", the_averages[count-1]-student_quiz_scores[count-1], "points lower than the average! :(\n"

def homework_average(all_homeworks):
    averages = []
    for each_homework in all_homeworks:
        each_average = find_average(each_homework)
        averages.append(each_average)
    return averages

def print_homework_averages(student_homework_scores,the_averages):
    count = 0
    for i in the_averages:
        print "The average for homework",count+1,"is:",i
        count+=1
        if student_homework_scores[count-1]>the_averages[count-1]:
            print "You did", student_homework_scores[count-1]-the_averages[count-1], "points higher than the average! :)\n"
        else:
            print "You did", the_averages[count-1]-student_homework_scores[count-1], "points lower than the average! :(\n"

def exam_average(all_exams):
    averages = []
    for each_exam in all_exams:
        each_average = find_average(each_exam)
        averages.append(each_average)
    return averages

def print_exam_averages(student_exam_scores,the_averages):
    count = 0
    for i in the_averages:
        print "The average for exam",count+1,"is:",i
        count+=1
        if student_exam_scores[count-1]>the_averages[count-1]:
            print "You did", student_exam_scores[count-1]-the_averages[count-1], "points higher than the average! :)\n"
        else:
            print "You did", the_averages[count-1]-student_exam_scores[count-1], "points lower than the average! :(\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: God! Are you going to drown us all in that code????

Comment: If you were using `numpy`, half of these functions would be standard array methods, and the other half could be defined with much less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing the comments about how much code there is, but here's one of your functions rewritten, so you can generalize this to your others:

```
def print_quiz_averages(student_quiz_scores,the_averages):                                                  
  for i, average in enumerate(the_averages):                                                              
    print "The average for quiz",i+1,"is:",i
    for student, student_data in student_quiz_scores.iteritems():                                       
      if student_data[i]>average:
          print("{:s} did {:.2f}% higher than average\n".format( student, student_data[i]-average))
      else:
          print("{:s} did {:.2f}% lower than average\n".format( student, -student_data[i]+average))
```

Comment: Thanks this is on the right track, but I'm looking for a way to do it so all of the data for each person is displayed at a time, instead of showing data for multiple people per quiz. So, I want to print all the scores for one person, and then move on to the next person.

Comment: Then you can switch the two "for" loops, so the `student_quiz_scores` wraps `the_averages`.

Comment: I'm not following your code, could you please update my code I've added in your answer? I'm not sure where I need to fix?